# PHP Help Array combinations

Tags: php, combinations

i have problem, no one can help me, i dont know where to search to what i want :(
I have for example array -

```
array:3 [
  "RSC" => ["RSC"],
  "MFS" => ["MFS"],
  "*" => ["*"],
]
```

So, i want to make script that will dynamically combine all array elements, for example -

```
array:1 [
  0 => "RSC MFS *"
]
array:1 [
  0 => "MFS RSC *"
]
array:1 [
  0 => "RSC * MFS"
]
array:1 [
  0 => "MFS * RSC"
]
array:1 [
  0 => "* RSC MFS"
]
array:1 [
  0 => "* MFS RSC"
]
```

There will be dynamical array, like there is codes that i want to combine.
And one more, i want to combine arrays like -

```
array:3 [
  "SOUND" => ['SOUND', 'ACOUSTIC', 'NCS', 'SCT'],
  "MFS" => ["MFS"],
  "RSC" => ["RSC"],
]
```

I want to get result like -

```
array:1 [
  0 => "SOUND MFS RSC"
]
array:1 [
  0 => "SOUND RSC MFS"
]
array:1 [
  0 => "MFS SOUND RSC"
]
array:1 [
  0 => "RSC SOUND MFS"
]
array:1 [
  0 => "ACOUSTIC MFS RSC"
]
array:1 [
  0 => "ACOUSTIC RSC MFS"
]
array:1 [
  0 => "MFS ACOUSTIC RSC"
]
array:1 [
  0 => "RSC ACOUSTIC MFS"
]
array:1 [
  0 => "NCS MFS RSC"
]
array:1 [
  0 => "NCS RSC MFS"
]
array:1 [
  0 => "MFS NCS RSC"
]
array:1 [
  0 => "RSC NCS MFS"
]
array:1 [
  0 => "SCT MFS RSC"
]
array:1 [
  0 => "SCT RSC MFS"
]
array:1 [
  0 => "MFS SCT RSC"
]
array:1 [
  0 => "RSC SCT MFS"
]
```

Thank you all guys for helping :)

I tried to find info with google help, nothing that i need and tried to tell chatgpt/bard what i want to do but they give me all time wrong code, so i dont have any idea how to make something like that

Comment: Try searching for "permutation of string combinations". You should be able to adopt these examples into your program.

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: Lemme guess, you're using these in a SQL query LIKE clause?

Comment: Should be noted that the number of permutations/combinations grows _factorially_, which is actually _worse_ than exponentially. If this is as AbraCadaver suspects, and these are destined for a SQL `LIKE` clause then you _very much_ need to adjust your database structure or you're in for some _very_ poor query performance.